# Outdated information on the privileges page

Tags: bug, status-completed, privileges-page

The [CW privilege page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/community-wiki) states in the second-to-last sentence that ”[CW] mode cannot be reversed”. As far as I know this is wrong; mods had the ability to reverse CWfication for some time now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've corrected this [on Meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/community-wiki) - the changes will propagate to this site in time.

Comment: That was fast! :)